# Monodroid ICS Could not open database file

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I'm using SQLite-net to read/access my database and it works fine on my Android 2.2 Emulator, but when I try and run it on an ICS ROM I get the following error:

```
Could not open database file: /data/data/MBR/files/MbrDB.db3
```

I'm not sure why it's working for 2.2 and not 4.0, does anyone know of any permissions that might have changed between versions?

To get the location I'm using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Thanks